# Get final price of configurable product in observer

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cart, observers, configurable-product

I have configurable products that have two prices (price and price per month). As the price of the product is fixed and only price per month can change with the options, I added an attribute (device_price) that will store the price, and the price attribute will have the price per month.

But of course when I add the product to the cart, I need to charge the price, not the price per month. so I used an observer for checkout_cart_product_add_after that has this code:

```
public function updatePrice(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {$item = $item->getParentItem();}

    if ($item->getProduct()->isConfigurable()){
        $device_price = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId())->getPrice_device();
        //set information
        $item->setCustomPrice($device_price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($device_price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    }
 }
```

But now on the cart I want to show both prices, final price is automatically there as I update it on the observer, but how do I get the price per month? (price of the product plus price of associates selected).

I suppose that the monthly price is somewhere on the quote item before I override it (do I actually override it or just say magento to look at the custom instead the original?).

What I was thinking is to get that monthly price and store it somewhere on the quoteItem, so that I can easily access on the cart to it.

How can I get the final price of the configurable product on the observer?

I am open to other suggestions if consider that there is a better way to approach it.

**EDIT SOLUTION**

Finally I have found where it was. I feel bad now because is actually very simple to get it :( I was trying to get the value from the item all the time but it is actually on the product inside the item

```
$_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();
```

this will give to you the final price of the configurable product with the options selected.

Maybe that can help someone else not wasting the time I did.

Comment: just look into the quote item with your debugger or a `var_dump` to see what you have

Comment: var_dump gives to me a big amount of data that I can't track very well. I am not using any IDE at the moment, working directly on files so I cant debug so much, I know, I need it.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and start to use an IDE and xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

The prices of your options you will get from the request.

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()
```